# How do I setup entrypoint initdb scripts for postgresql in docker?

Tags: postgresql, docker, synology

I have setup a postgresql database on my Synology NAS using Docker. The container boots up and I can access postgresql using both ssh (psql) and DataGrip. But the issue is that the init scripts that I have created don't work as expected, they don't create any databases.

When I add another init script but with a different user I can see that role being added when checking the roles folder (in DataGrip) but I never see any database with the same name. I can also not see the roles that my init scripts are creating which I see in DataGrip when using psql \du.

So since the users are being created I assume the init scripts in my config folder are being run, but why are the databases not create not the roles being visible when using psql \du?

Note: I have done prune on the posgres image and emptied the data folder before running docker-compose up -d to be sure there are no old things left that give me a problem.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgresql:
    container_name: postgresql
    restart: always
    image: postgres:latest
    network_mode: "bridge"
    environment: 
    - TZ=Europe/Stockholm
    - VERSION=latest
    - POSTGRES_USER=synology
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=synology
    ports:
    - "3456:5432"

    volumes:
    - /volume1/docker/postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    - /volume1/docker/postgresql/config:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

    cap_add:
    - DAC_READ_SEARCH
    - NET_BIND_SERVICE
    - SETGID
    - SETUID
    - SYS_ADMIN
    - SYS_PTRACE

    security_opt:
    - apparmor:unconfined
```

init.sql

```
CREATE USER synology with encrypted password 'synology';
CREATE DATABASE synology;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE synology TO synology;
```

[image]

Anyone got any ideas what might be wrong here?

**UPDATE:** I'm starting to think that when I use the psql command I accesse the Synology local DB and not the one in my container... but still doesn't explain why only the users are created and not my databases.

Comment: Please don't post files as images. Images are really hard to copy-paste for someone who wants to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Added the code as well ;)

Comment: The scripts in docker-entrypoint-initdb.d are *only* run if no databases exist when the container starts. You map a volume, so unless that volume is empty, nothing will be run. See the warning under "Initialization scripts" here: https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/

Comment: The /data folder is empty when I run docker-compose up -d, if I remove the /data folder from my Synology volume I get an error, ERROR: for postgresql  Cannot start service postgresql: Bind mount failed: '/volume1/docker/postgresql/data' does not exists

Comment: But the weird part is that the users are created. but not the databases, I have tried to change the user and password to postgres in the docker-compose.yml file and then add two different sql scripts in the config folder, both users get created (when looking through DataGrip), but can't see the roles if I login using psql as postgres user.

Comment: I can also not see the users in the pg_hba.conf file, only the postgres user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I was being a little stupid here, I was basically accessing the Synology postgres DB when just running the psql command. I first need open up bash in the container `docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID bash` and then run `psql -U postgres`, then I can list the databases and users and see that they all got created.